# How to retrieve values from normalized table in one line per dataset?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stored data into several MySQL 5.x tables in order to normalize, now I am struggling on how to retrieve this data in one line per dataset.

E.g.

**Table 1: articles**, holding also 2 values in this example per article

```
article_id | make | model
1            Audi   A3
```

**Table 2: article_attributes**, where one article can have several attributes

```
article_id | attr_id
1            1
1            2
2            1
```

**Table 3: article_attribute_names**

```
attr_id | name
1         Turbo
2         Airbag
```

Now I want to retrieve it, with one line per dataset

e.g.

```
SELECT a.*, attr_n.name AS function
FROM `articles` a
LEFT JOIN article_attributes AS attr ON a.article_id = attr.article_id
LEFT JOIN article_attribute_names AS attr_n ON attr_n.attr_id = attr.attr_id
-- group by attr.article_id
```

This will gives me:

```
article_id | Make | Model  | function
1            Audi   A3       Turbo
1            Audi   A3       Airbag
```

But I am looking for something like this:

```
article_id | Make | Model  | function1 | function2
1            Audi   A3       Turbo       Airbag
```

Is this even possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: "Is this even possible, and if yes, how?" yes this is called Pivotting.. How? search on stackoverflow ["mysql pivot table"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot+table) or ["mysql convert records to columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+convert+records+to+columns)

Comment: You can use the GROUP_CONCAT function to combine the column from article_attributes_names into a single column of comma separated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to put the values into a delimited field using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(an.name) AS functions
FROM articles a LEFT JOIN
     article_attributes aa
     ON a.article_id = aa.article_id LEFT JOIN
     article_attribute_names aan
     ON aan.attr_id = aa.attr_id
GROUP BY a.article_id;
```

Aggregating by `article_id` is okay, assuming that the id is unique (or equivalently declared as a primary key).

If you actually want the results in separate columns, that is more challenging.  If you know there are at most two (as in your example), just use aggregation:

```
SELECT a.*, MIN(an.name) AS function1,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(an.name) <> MAX(an.name)
             THEN MAX(an.name)
        END) as function2
FROM articles a LEFT JOIN
     article_attributes aa
     ON a.article_id = aa.article_id LEFT JOIN
     article_attribute_names aan
     ON aan.attr_id = aa.attr_id
GROUP BY a.article_id;
```